# Insert One Variable into Another with PHP

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to insert these $lat and $lng variable into the final $html variable with no success.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?..

Much Appreciated.

```
<?php
$lat = '33.599968';
$lng = '-112.119499';
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap? center=$lat,$lng&zoom=13&size=665x400&markers=color:red|$lat,$lng&sensor=false';
$html = '<img border="0" src="$url" width="665" height="400" border="1"></a>';

echo $lat;
echo $lng; 
echo $url;
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes. Single quotes treat the string as a literal, so variables aren't interpolated.

Comment: You're writing HTML, so you should run your data (`$url` in particular since it contains `&` characters) through `htmlspecialchars()` before inserting into a fragment of HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two changes in the url line:

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$lat,$lng&zoom=13&size=665x400&markers=color:red|$lat,$lng&sensor=false";
```

" instead of ' so that php will evaluate $lat,$lng

And you want remove the space before center:

... staticmap? center ...

becomes

... staticmap?center ...

Answer (score 0):

Strings delimited with double quotes `"` interpolate variables, strings delimited with single quotes `'` do not. Use `"`.